# Allow user to input shortcode into wordpress widget

Tags: plugins, shortcode

This is my first widget, so I'm new to this, but I want the ability to add 6 different shortcodes to the widget that the user can set.

The question is this, how do I get the plugin to allow the user to do this and how do I get the plugin to execute the shortcodes?

Answer (score 0):

Very rough and partly [cribbed from the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget), but it should get you started:

```
class My_SC_Widget extends WP_Widget {

  private $shortcodes = array(
    'sc1' => '[sc1]',
    'sc2' => '[sc2]',
    'sc3' => '[sc3]',
  );

  function __construct() {
    // Instantiate the parent object
    parent::__construct( false, 'My SC Widget' );
  }

  function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    if (isset($instance['my_shortcode_widgets']) && array_key_exists($instance['my_shortcode_widgets'],$this->shortcodes)) {
      echo do_shortcode($this->shortcodes[$instance['my_shortcode_widgets']]);
    }
  }

  function update( $new_instance, $instance ) {
    // Save widget options
    if (isset($new_instance['my_shortcode_widgets']) && array_key_exists($new_instance['my_shortcode_widgets'],$this->shortcodes)) {
      $instance['my_shortcode_widgets'] = $new_instance['my_shortcode_widgets'];
    }

    return $instance;
  }

  function form( $instance ) {
    echo '<select name="'.$this->get_field_name('my_shortcode_widgets').'">';
      foreach ($this->shortcodes as $k => $v) {
        echo '<option value="'.$k.'" '.selected( $instance['my_shortcode_widgets'], $k ).'>'.$k.'</option>'; 
      }
    echo '</select>';
  }
}

function myplugin_register_widgets() {
  register_widget( 'My_SC_Widget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myplugin_register_widgets' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but this works with an array and I need the ability for the user to enter a wide variation of shortcodes. This plugin works in conjunction of another plugin that sets the shortcodes used by mine. Thanks again

Comment: Your question specifically states that "I want the ability to add 6 different shortcodes to the widget that the user can set." I therefore provided code that would allow particular shortcodes to be used. To allow any shortcodes to run it is a relatively simple edit to the `form` and the `widget` methods.

Comment: Your right wrong choice of words, sorry, the widget will need 6 places for user to enter shortcode and 6 places for titles above each shortcode entry.